# Get JS object data from user input

Tags: javascript, html, object, search, user-input

Acceptance Criteria: Enter a name and have the person's extension returned to the UI onClick or when pressing "return".

I am looking for suggestions on how to get this to work.

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAQ42.png)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SearchFunction</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var extensionList = {

                Abby: '8845',   
                David: '8871',  
                Jim: '8890', 
                Lewis: '8804',
            };

            var returnLookUp = function(){
                var getInfo = document.getElementById("thisSearch");
                var SearchInfo = thisSearch.value;
                /*......?*/
            }

        </script>
        <form>
            <input id="thisSearch" type="text" placeholder="enter name">
            <button onClick = "returnLookUp();">Find</button>
            <input id="output" name="output" type="text" size="30">
            <br><br>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ```return extensionList[SearchInfo];```

Comment: If I type in the name 'David' I would like the page to return his extension, 8871. I can get information from the extensionList object by using console.log(extensionList.Jim) but I have not been able to do anything like console.log(extensionList.SearchInfo).

Comment: Re-read my code. Not ```extensionList.SearchInfo``` but ```extensionList[SearchInfo]```. If ```searchInfo = 'Jim'``` it will be equivalent to ```extensionList["Jim"]``` which is the same as ```extentsionList.Jim```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit button type is defined. So by default it will be button `type ="submit"`. in that case it will try to submit the form. button `type="button"` can be use or to prevent the default behaviour, `preventDefault()` can be used

`extensionList[thisSearch.value]` is use to get the value of the key from the object, `extensionList` is the object, `thisSearch.value` will be the input which is same as the key of the object

```js
var extensionList = {

  Abby: '8845',
  David: '8871',
  Jim: '8890',
  Lewis: '8804',
};

var returnLookUp = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var getInfo = document.getElementById("thisSearch");
  document.getElementById("output").value = extensionList[thisSearch.value];

}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="thisSearch" type="text" placeholder="enter name">
  <button onClick="returnLookUp(event);">Find</button>
  <input id="output" name="output" type="text" size="30">
  <br><br>
</form>
```